# Redirect a url along with .htaccess and re-write rules gone wrong

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect http://localhost/anay-bose to http://localhost/anay-bose/1338.html (actual and valid url) via .htaccess

Here's my rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$ /anaybose/$1 [R=301]
Redirect /anay-bose http://localhost/anay-bose/1338.html
```

Problem is it's redirecting to a url such as http://localhost/anay-bose/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html/1338.html

Lots of 1338.html while I just need one 1338.html

Looking for an insight.

Comment: you are in an endless loop. anay-bose redirects everything starting with /anay-bose to anay-bose/1338.html. But anay-bose/1338.html matches the rule again and anay-bose is redirected again.
try
####
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 anay-bose http://localhost/anay-bose/1338.html

Comment: _“Looking for an insight”_ - then start by reading the documentation maybe? For `Redirect`, it clearly explains how this directive does _prefix_ matching on the URL path, and appends any excess to the target URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enhance it a little via [RedirectMatch Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

```
RedirectMatch ^/anay-bose$ http://localhost/anay-bose/1338.html
```